# Why does "load_model" cause RAM memory problems while predicting?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I trained neural network (transformer architecture) and saved it by using:

```
model.save(directory + args.name, save_format="tf")
```

After that, I want to load the model again with another script to test it by letting it make iterative predictions:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model(args.model)
for i in range(very_big_number):
    out, _ = model(something, training=False)
```

However, I have noticed that the RAM usage increases with each prediction and I don't know why. At some point the programme stops because there is no more memory available. You can also see the RAM consumption in the following screenshot:

[image: RAM usage while training]

If I use the same architecture, but only load the weights of the model with `model.load_weigts( ... )`, I do not have the problem.

My question now is, why does `load_model` seem to cause this and how do I solve the problem?

I'm using tensorflow 2.5.0.

**Edit:**

As I was not able to solve the problem and the answers did not help either, I simply used the `load_weights` method so that I created a new model and loaded the weights of the saved model like this:

```
model = myModel()
saved_model = load_model(args.model)
model.load_weights(saved_model + "/variables/variables")
```

In this way, the usage of RAM remained constant. Nevertheless an non-optimal solution, in my opinion.

Comment: are you loading model every time, that you have to predict, or you load once and take the predictions on the sequence of the data?

Comment: I only load the model once

Comment: Ok, I tried to answer you question below :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental difference between `load_model` and `load_weights`. When you save an model using `save_model` you save the following things:

A Keras model consists of multiple components:

- The architecture, or configuration, which specifies what layers the model contain, and how they're connected.
- A set of weights values (the "state of the model").
- An optimizer (defined by compiling the model).
- A set of losses and metrics (defined by compiling the model or calling
  add_loss() or add_metric()).

However when you save the weights using `save_weights`, you only saves the weights, and this is useful for the `inference` purpose, while when you want to resume the training process, you need a `model` object, that is the reason we save everything in the model. When you just want to predict and get the result `save_weights` is enough. To learn more, you can check the documentation of [save/load models](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize).

So, as you can see when you do `load_model`, it has many things to load as compared to `load_weights`, thus it will have more overhead hence your RAM usage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware that significantly more data is stored and that the RAM is therefore also used more when using ```save_model```. As you can see in the code above, I only load the model once and only let it predict iteratively, which should not actually increase the RAM. However, the RAM usage strangely increases with each iteration and I think your solution does not answer this behaviour.

Comment: Yes Ok, so `something` is your batch input?

Comment: Also, there seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33030 

Please check if some solutions applies to you.

Comment: `gc.collect()` followed by Keras Clear Session might work too, but you have to check for yourself, because it's very hard to find out what's wrong : https://medium.com/dive-into-ml-ai/dealing-with-memory-leak-issue-in-keras-model-training-e703907a6501

Comment: Yes, it is actually a more complicated code, which I have greatly reduced here. I don't think it should be a problem, because the code doesn't cause any problems with ``model.load_weights`` as already described. So the problem really seems to be with ``load_model``. It almost seems as if the graph (or whatever is behind it) is not reset after each iteration, so that the space used for the calculations of old inputs is not redistributed.

Comment: Yes, I have already found this article, but it did not help me.

Comment: Oops, Ok. there is known issue in github issue as well about this.

Comment: I also already know the Github issue, but unfortunately the solutions of that thread don't help either. Besides, it never seems to be about ``load_model`` being the actual problem.

Comment: I believe what is happening is you are creating a new instance of the model at each iteration. Why not just use model.predict to avoid the problem.

Comment: No, no new model is being created then. I use the ```__call__``` method instead of the ```predict``` method because I have overridden it on my own to adapt it to a desired behaviour. There is therefore no error at this point.

Answer (score 0):

model.predict_on_batch will solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).